# Inserting into a Linked List after nth Element

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working with Linked List and attempting to insert a new node with data d after the where'th node. For some reason I am getting incorrect results. Here is my code:

```
void insertAfter(int d, int where )  
{
    struct list * marker = head;
    struct list * new;

    while(marker -> data != where)
        marker = marker -> next;
    new = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    new -> next = marker -> next; 
    marker -> next = new;
    new -> data = d; 
}
```

Comment: `marker -> data != where` does not mean the nth

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest a safer version along with some commentary:

```
void insertAfter(int d, int where )  
{
    struct list * marker = head; /* it's a little odd that you have named your node struct list */
    struct list * new;

    while(marker && marker->data != where) /* we don't want to end up dereferencing a null pointer */
        marker = marker->next;

    if (!marker) /* we've reached the end of the list and no element was found */
    {
        printf("Element with data %d not found\n", where); /* print some diagnostics */
        return; /* let's exit here, no reason to hang about */
    }

    /* if we are here then we've found our element */

    struct list * next_node = marker->next; /* let's save the next node */

    new = malloc(sizeof(struct list)); /* it is bad practice to cast the result of malloc */
    new->data = d;

    marker->next = new; /* marker now points to the new node */

    new->next = next_node; /* the new node now points to the one marker originally pointed to */
}
```

Regarding the casting of `malloc` have a read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do modify your code like this(the first node is 0th node, the second node is 1th in my this code):

```
void insertAfter(int d, int where )  
{
    struct list * marker = head;
    struct list * new;
    int count = 0;

    while(count < where)
    {
        count++;
        marker = marker -> next;
    }
    new = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    new -> next = marker -> next; 
    marker -> next = new;
    new -> data = d; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is inserting the new node after the node whose data==where, not the where'th node. You can write it like this:

```
int i;
for(i=1; i<where; i++)
    marker = marker->next;
```

Besides, it's better to check if `marker` reaches a `NULL`, or when the program tries to read `marker->next` or `marker->data`, there will be an abort.